# c# delete excel sheets using for loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete excel sheets using for loop except selected sheet by User using Dropdown menu in asp.net web application. So, I have written a code in c#.

```
int index = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
int max = DropDownList1.Items.Count;
int i=3;
for (i=1; i <= max; i++)
{
    if (i != index+1)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet worksheets = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[i];
        worksheets.Delete();
    }

}
```

And I am getting an error like this -

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid index.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'

Comment: I believe the indexing starts at zero! You are starting at 1. Do you have 2 worksheets in the book? [0] & [1]

Comment: How many worksheets does your Excel file have?

Comment: There are three worksheets in Workbook. And I have done research that for Sheets index is starting from 1 only

Answer (score 2):

Both `xlWorkBook.Sheets` and `DropDownList1.SelectedIndex` indexes starts at `0`, not `1`, so you need to change your loop like this:

```
int index = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
int max = DropDownList1.Items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    if (i != index)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet worksheets = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[i];
        worksheets.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that while deleting a worksheet, index position might get change so you'll also need to decrease the int value to get correct index otherwise you'll again get the same exception while deleting the sheets afterwards or lead to delete a sheet which you dont want to delete

```
int index = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
int max = DropDownList1.Items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    if (i != index)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[i];
        worksheet.Delete();

        //decrease the value
        --i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but anyhow when I reversed the loop, It started working.

```
for (i=max; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (i != index+1)
    {
         Excel.Worksheet worksheets = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[i];
         worksheets.Delete();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is because if you delete sheet 2 then sheet 3 *becomes* sheet 2 (all the indexes above 2 drop down one).

Comment: Thus, going from highest to lowest avoids this issue - the only indexes it will impact are those it has already looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Lets index=5;
The error means that the sheet at index 5 is not available.
You are correct that the index of worksheet starts with 1 and not 0.

I have done some modification in your code. I am performing an additional check of your current index (i) with the Sheets count present in the workbook to skip the **Bad Index Error.** Hope this will work.

```
 using System;
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {     
         int i = 3, max = 5, index = 1;
         string filePath = @"C:\Users\anandra\Desktop\Book1.xlsx";
         Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
         Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
         for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
         {
           //Adding an extra check here to skip your error
             if (i != index + 1 && workBook.Sheets.Count>i )
             {
                 Excel.Worksheet worksheets = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[i];
                 excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                 worksheets.Delete();
                 excelApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
                 //Decreasing the value of index and i as after deleting the sheet the index will start agarin from 1.
                 i--;
                 index--;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```